# How can I observe if a coroutine channel is hanging? Do I need to close it?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

A bit of a background: My app uses screen components which can include multiple usecasemodels.
These usecasemodels launch network request coroutines in the background and communicate with the screen via a channel which broadcasts states.

When the user navigates to a different screen, the job of the corresponding screen scope is cancelled and the screen is destroyed.

**My first question is:** What happens to the channel? Do I still need to close it or has it been closed implicitly?

**My second question is:** How can I test/observe myself if the channels are still hanging somewhere trying to broadcast to a receiver (screen) that no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

After actually reading the documentation more carefully, I believe the solution is to invokeOnClose on the channel suspected to hang.

For example:

```
channel.invokeOnClose {
    print("channel closed")
}
```

Then the application can be run and start navigating to different screens. If the "channel closed" message is printed then it's all good, otherwise it means that the channel is hanging.

In my case, the channel was not closed, therefore I need to call channel.close() in the appropriate lifecycle place.